# Tomcat 9 DIGEST with JDBCRealm - accepts only digests, not passwords

Tags: tomcat, digest-authentication, jdbcrealm

Newly installed tomcat 9 - and migrated applications from tomcat 8 to tomcat 9.

To authenticate my config is using JDBCRealm with a mysql database. The config below ran very well with tomcat 8 but on tomcat 9 accepted only the password digests directly instead of the "human" passwords (the digests are stored in the table tomcat_users) directly instead of the usual passwords. It seems hence that the digest algorithm MD5 be here not executed when a human readable password is submitted in the FORM login page.

The config inside server.xml is

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm" connectionName=“..." connectionPassword=“..." connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/TOMSCHEMA" digest="MD5" driverName="org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver" roleNameCol="role_name" userCredCol="password" userNameCol="user_name" userRoleTable="tomcat_users_roles" userTable="tomcat_users"/>
```

The authentication method is FORM for an application and DIGEST for the corresponding API inside another application. Both apps sees each other in a cross context. The web.xml of the application contains:

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>NAME</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/WEB-INF/security/protected/login.jsp</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/WEB-INF/security/protected/error.jsp</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

What could be wrong here? It is all quite "standard" ... What shell I do in order to have with the FORM authentication page again a human password input using DIGEST as I had with tomcat 8?

Thank you very much in advance

Regards

Answer (score 5):

Now you need to add in server.xml additional lines to conform old digesting method:

```html
     <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm"
        driverName="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver"
        connectionURL="jdbc:derby:/tomcat/db/zzz;create=false"
        connectionName="zzz"
        connectionPassword="zzz"
        userTable="login"
        userNameCol="login"
        userCredCol="passwd"
        userRoleTable="roles"
        roleNameCol="role"
      >
        <CredentialHandler className="org.apache.catalina.realm.MessageDigestCredentialHandler"
          algorithm="MD5"
          iterations="1"
          saltlenght="0"
        />
      </Realm>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Interestingly, I didn't find this in Tomcat documentation.